# Question on the Borel subgroup of $SO(2n)(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

I am wondering what it looks like the maximal torus of the Borel subgroup of $SO(2n)(\mathbb{R})$.

I guess that $(2 \times 2)$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos \theta  \end{pmatrix}$ occurs in the diagonal as well $t \in \mathbb{R}^{\times}$.

Thank you for your comment in advance.

Comment: Any conjugate of a maximal torus is again a maximal torus. So there is no "the" maximal torus, if there is one at all then there are many. --- The same holds true for "the" Borel subgroup of your title. By the way, your title does not describe the question that well, does it?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, Oh, I am sorry. I mean the maximal torus of the Borel subgroup of $SO(2n)(\mathbb{R})$. Thanks!

Comment: What do you think is "the Borel subgroup" of $SO(2n)$? How are Borel subgroups defined for (compact) real Lie groups?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, I mean the upper triangular matrix group for the Borel subgroup of non-compact $SO(2n)(R)$. When $SO(2n)(R)$ is compact, the Borel subgroup of $SO(2n)(R)$ is itself.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, If I am mistaken, I would appreciate you let me know it.

Comment: I think if most people see $SO(2n)(\mathbb R)$ they would assume what is meant is with respect to the standard Euclidean scalar product, so that this group is automatically compact. If you mean a more general setting, you should write that in the question. Also, your cases are inconsistent: the only upper-triangular matrices which are orthogonal (wrt the standard Euclidean product) are diagonal. (The more compact a group is, the less unipotent elements it has.)

Comment: Chiming in with Torsten. On the side of algebraic groups people often use the quadratic form of a maximal Witt index when discussing orthogonal groups. The details have become somewhat rusty in my brain, but IIRC you want the preserved form to be $$x_1x_{2n}+x_2x_{2n-1}+x_3x_{2n-2}+\cdots+x_nx_{n+1}$$ to get the usual  situation that a Borel subgroup consists of upper triangular matrices in the group. I have never studied Lie groups enough to say anything at all how the conventions/terminology work there.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no** Borel subgroup of $SO(n)$ as it is compact. You can say $SO(n)$ is the only parabolic subgroup of itself but it is still not Borel.

To have Borel subgroups a (semisimple) group must be what is called quasi-split. The only real forms of the complex special orthogonal group that are quasi-split are those of the form $SO(n,n), SO(n,n+1), SO(n,n+2)$. The first two being the split case in even and odd dimensions respectively and the last being the non-split case in even dimensions (no non-split, quasi-split case in odd dimensions)

Over the complex numbers, all tori are contained in a Borel subgroup and all are conjugate so nothing to say really there but it is important to note there is more than one and this is true in the real forms as well. Indeed there will be one for every Borel subgroup opposite to the starting one which is an affine space of dimension equal to that of the unipotent radical.

In the split case I think they should be split tori (i.e. diagonalisable). In the quasi-split case I'm less sure. From [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/241535/quasi-split-tori-and-algebraic-groups) we can see that if the group was adjoint or simply connected then the tori would have to be quasi-split ones but $SO(n,n+2)$ is neither (indeed it's not even connected but I assume we'd implicitly pass to the connected component of the identity)

Comment: You are confusing Borel and minimal parabolic.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike at which point? Minimal parabolic coincides with Borel wherever the latter is defined (i.e. the quasi-split case)

Comment: One can define both in the non-quasi split case as well (Humphreys does it) and they are different. I remember answering this question few months ago.

Comment: @Callum, Thanks for good answer. But I guess that SO(n,n+2) is not quasi-split. Rather, SO(n+2,n) is quasi split.

Comment: @Andrew those groups are isomorphic

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike I am unfamiliar with the definition you are referring to. We could still define a Borel subgroup as a maximal solvable subgroup, perhaps, but I haven't seen this used much over the reals. Instead I see it more commonly defined as complexifying to a Borel (or the Lie algebra version at least). Indeed, the definition I am most familiar with for quasi-split is "admitting a Borel subgroup". I can see there could be a useful distinction there but I don't know that is what the question is asking about.

Comment: @Callum, as far as I know, isomorphism doesn’t preserve quasi-splitness.

Comment: @Andrew yes it does. Quasi-split means contains a Borel subgroup and a Lie group isomorphism will take a Borel subgroup into another Borel subgroup. Lie group isomorphism preserves everything you would care about Lie groups from a Lie theory perspective. Note $SO(n+2,n), SO(n,n+2)$ have the same Satake diagram for example.